# Kali Linux Pfsense Virtualbox

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

I have a Kali Linux installed as a host machine. The Kali Linux machine is on a 192.168.0.1/24 IP range which is assigned on my wireless home network. My home lab is on a 192.168.5.0/24 (NAT Network) hosted on Virtualbox environment which has my pfsense firewall (192.168.5.1) and my domain controller (192.168.5.205).

What am I trying to do is I want to be able to use my Kali Linux machine to hack my home lab. The problem I have is that my Kali Linux does not seem to be able to get to the 192.168.5.0/24 network. How can I possible make this happen? I have checked my firewall rules to see if there is anything blocking my Kali Linux.